# Create a stack of cards

Tags: java, stack

I currently have the following card class;

```
public class Card {

    /** hearts, diamond, club, spades */
    private String suit;

    /** ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, jack, queen, king */
    private String rank;

    /** 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 */
    private int pointValue;

    public Card(String cardSuit, String cardRank, int cardPointValue) {
        /** initialise a new card with the given values for suit rank and point value */
        suit = cardSuit;
        rank = cardRank;
        pointValue = cardPointValue;
    }

    /** accessor methods - help client access private instance fields - oop*/
    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public String getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public int getPointValue() {
        return pointValue;
    }

    /** test to see if card given from values above matches card given as parameter to this argument*/
    public boolean matches(Card otherCard) {
        return otherCard.getSuit().equals(this.getSuit())
        && otherCard.getRank().equals(this.getRank())
        && otherCard.getPointValue() == this.getPointValue();
    }

    /** overriding toString method allows us to output meaningful content as default function returns gibberish (essentially) */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return rank + " of " + suit + " (point value = " + pointValue + ")";
    }
}
```

I would like to create a stack of all possible combinations of cards that displays the output along the line of;

```
Six of Hearts (value = 6)
Ace of Clubs (value = 1)
```

I have the following deck class but Im stuck where to go from here;

```
public class Deck {
    String suit[] = {"Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades"};
    String rank[] = {"Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "King", "Queen", "Ace"};
    int pointValue[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
    Card[] deck = new Card[52];
}
```

thanks

Comment: `Deck` has an array of `Card`s, but each element of that array is null.  Consider adding a constructor to initialize each element.  Also, it's not clear why `Deck` would have `suit[]`, `rank[]`, and `pointValue[]` (since each card defines those properties for itself).

Comment: Iterate over the `suit`s, iterate over the `rank`s, create a `Card` for each combination. --- Some remarks on the code: suits and ranks are prime candidates for `Enum`s. I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one from `oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). - While it is possible to write the array-brackets after the variable name, we normally write them after the type since they influence the type (`String suit[]` -> `String[] suit`, `String rank[]` -> `String[] rank`)

Comment: so where should I place the enum data types, in my card class or deck class?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the combination like this:

```
List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
for(int i=0;i<suit.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;i<rank.length;j++)
    {
        Card card = new Card(suit[i], rank[j], pointValue[j]);
        deck.add(card);
    }
}
```

Comment: i cannot use arraylists unfortunately